# Changing React Select options prop dynamically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I have two select inputs via React Select. The options prop of my second select should change dynamically based on the value in the first react Select. What is the best way to do this?

my first select:

```
      <Select
        styles={colourStyles}
        className="basic-single"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isSearchable={isSearchable}
        placeholder="Select service category"
        name="color"
        options={serviceCategoriesPrimary}
        onChange={(value) =>
          value !== null ? setSelectValue(value.value) : setSelectValue("")
        }
      />
```

my second select:

```
      <Select
        styles={colourStyles}
        className="basic-single"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isSearchable={isSearchable}
        isDisabled={selectValue === "" ? true : false}
        placeholder="Select secondary category"
        name="color"
        options={handleChooseOptions}
      />
```

```
  const handleChooseOptions = () => {
    if(selectValue === 'Health Care'){
      return options1
    }else{
      return options2
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `optionsFunction` is more complicated than what your example shows, I would memoize the output of that `optionsFunction` and pass it as a prop to the second select.

The `optionsFunction` will be re-run every time the `selectValue` changes.

When `optionsFunction` re-runs it will update the reference to select2Options, re-rendering the second select.

```
const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(null); 

const select2Options = useMemo(() => {
   if(selectValue === 'Health Care')
       return options1 // update pointer

   return options2 // update pointer
}, [selectValue]) // rerun function in useMemo on selectValue changes

return (
<>
    <Select
        {/*  will change the dependency of useMemo, re-running the `optionsFunction`, and updating the reference of `select2Options` if necessary */}
        onChange={value => setSelectValue(value)} 
    ></Select>
    <Select options={select2Options}></Select>
</>
)
```

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @BenShekhtman glad to hear, don't forget to mark the question as answered ^^

Answer (score 1):

first Select:

```
<Select
    styles={colourStyles}
    className="basic-single"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    isClearable={isClearable}
    isSearchable={isSearchable}
    placeholder="Select service category"
    name="color"
    options={serviceCategoriesPrimary}
    onChange={(value) =>
      value !== null ? setSelectValue(value.value) : setSelectValue("")
    }
  />
```

Second Select:

```
<Select
    styles={colourStyles}
    className="basic-single"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    isClearable={isClearable}
    isSearchable={isSearchable}
    isDisabled={selectValue === "" ? true : false}
    placeholder="Select secondary category"
    name="color"
    options={selectValue === 'Health Care' ? options1 : options2}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can here in the following code how we have use **HandleChangeOptions** componet in select option.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { payloadTemplate } from '../../utils/requestype'
import { constructPayload } from '../../utils'


const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48

export default function LongMenu(props) {
    const [ anchorEl, setAnchorEl ] = React.useState(null)
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl)

    const handleClick = React.useCallback(event => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    }, [])

    const handleClose = React.useCallback(value => {
        const options = props.loadInitEqtyValues.EQUITY_REQUEST_TYPE.map(rt => rt.NAME)
        if (options.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            const rows = props.managefunds
            rows.push({
                checked: false,
                data: {
                    ...constructPayload(props.formDesc[value], props.criteria, props.input, props.selectedClient, payloadTemplate),
                    accountId: uuidv4(),
                    requestor: 'karthikeyan.anbalagan@temp.com',
                    requestType: value
                },
                formDesc: props.formDesc[value],
                isCollapsed: false,
                validationErrors: []
            })
            props.handleRequestType({label: 'requesttype', managefunds: rows, requesttype: value})
            setAnchorEl(null)
        }
    }, [ props.managefunds, props.loadInitEqtyValues ])

    const HandleChangeOptions = React.useCallback(() => {
        const options = props.loadInitEqtyValues.EQUITY_REQUEST_TYPE.map(rt => rt.NAME)
        if (props.requesttype.split('-').at(0) === '') {
            return options.map(option => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option}
                    onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose(option))}
                >
                    {option}
                </MenuItem>
            ))
        } else if (props.requesttype.split('-').at(0) === 'US ') {
            const options = props.loadInitEqtyValues.EQUITY_REQUEST_TYPE.map(rt => rt.NAME).filter(ft => ft.startsWith('US'))
            return options.map(option => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option}
                    onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose(option))}
                >
                    {option}
                </MenuItem>
            ))
        } else if (props.requesttype.split('-').at(0) === 'Canada ') {
            const options = props.loadInitEqtyValues.EQUITY_REQUEST_TYPE.map(rt => rt.NAME).filter(ft => ft.startsWith('Canada'))
            return options.map(option => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option}
                    onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose(option))}
                >
                    {option}
                </MenuItem>
            ))
        } else {
            const options = props.loadInitEqtyValues.EQUITY_REQUEST_TYPE.map(rt => rt.NAME).filter(ft => !ft.includes('Canada') && !ft.includes('US'))
            return options.map(option => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option}
                    onClick={React.useCallback(() => handleClose(option))}
                >
                    {option}
                </MenuItem>
            ))
        }
    }, [ props.requesttype, props.loadInitEqtyValues ])

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                aria-label='more'
                id='long-button'
                variant={'outlined'}
                aria-controls={open ? 'long-menu' : undefined}
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup='true'
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                + Add request
            </Button>
            <Menu
                id='long-menu'
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'long-button',
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                PaperProps={{
                    style: {
                        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 6.5,
                        width: '40ch',
                    },
                }}
            >
                {<HandleChangeOptions/>}
            </Menu>
        </>
    )
}
```